# Can't upload image files to permanent folder in MAMP. Newbie

Tags: php, permissions, mamp

I am trying out some php/mysql resources and am stuck on uploading images to permanent folder with MAMP. 
This is the form:

```
<form action="create_user.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" size="20" /><br />
<label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" size="20" /><br />
<label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" size="50" /><br />
<label for="facebook_url">Facebook URL:</label>
<input type="text" name="facebook_url" size="50" /><br />
<label for="twitter_handle">Twitter Handle:</label>
<input type="text" name="twitter_handle" size="20" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<label for="user_pic">Upload a picture:</label>
<input type="file" name="user_pic" size="30" /><br />    
<label for="bio">Bio:</label>
<textarea name="bio" cols="40" rows="10"/></textarea>
</fieldset>
<br />
```

This is the code in my script interacting with the form:

```
$upload_dir = SITE_ROOT . "missmanphpmysql/uploads/profile_pics/";
$image_fieldname = "user_pic";
```

This is the function and custom function to check for permissions and the like:

```
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'], $upload_filename)
 or handle_error("we had a problem saving your image to " .
              "its permanent location.",
              "permissions or related error moving " .
              "file to {$upload_filename}");
```

All I get is the above error message. I have tried to change the permissions in finder and chmod but I may be doing it wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is how the $upload_filename function is defined  $now = time();
while (file_exists($upload_filename = $upload_dir . $now .
                                     '-' .
                                     $_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'])) {
    $now++;
}

Comment: Hi. I worked it out, finally. I needed to constants: SITE_ROOT for the root of the website and SITE_PATH going from the file system to the upload folder in order to upload images. I then concatenated this with "missmanphpmysql/uploads/profile_pics/" for $upload_dir.                                       define("SITE_ROOT", "/sandbox/missmanphpmysql");
define("SITE_PATH", "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sandbox/missmanphpmysql"); Thanks for all your help anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the folder permission correctly? profile_pics needs write permission. Try to use terminal and set 'chmod 777 profile_pics'.

Comment: Hi I went to that directory and added those permissions and it now has these permissions drwxrwxrwx. Still no dice .

Comment: You can try to print out what is you $upload_filename. I don't see you define it anywhere.

Comment: This how I define it: $now = time(); while (file_exists($upload_filename = $upload_dir . $now . '-' . $_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'])) { $now++; } This is the error message I get: The following system-level message was received: permissions or related error moving file to /sandbox/missmanphpmysql/uploads/profile_pics/1384334923-IMG_0397.JPG. Thanks again for looking at this for me.

Comment: how about your SITE_ROOT? do you really have /sandbox/ folder?

Comment: hey, yeah that comes from Applcations/MAMP/htdocs/sandbox/ etc. Thanks again.

Comment: Then your full path should be /Applcations/MAMP/htdocs/sandbox/missmanphpmysql/uploads/profile_pics/1384334923-IMG_0397.JPG.

You can use __DIR__ to find out your php code path instead of hard coding it.

Comment: Hi. Still Getting permission issues. How does this dir work? Teach me.

Comment: Turns out you were right. See above, I needed two constants: SITE_ROOT AND SITE_PATH from /Applcations/MAMP/htdocs/sandbox/missmanphpmysql/uploads/profile_pics/Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  [constants dir php](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) in $upload_filename.
And after that make sure upload filename is correct no consecutive Dir sept or missing ones.

Make sure you close the form tag also.

Comment: Litechip, thanks for your time. I'm new to this, could you tell what you mean by using DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR constants dir php in $upoad_filename? I gave $upload_dir a constant SITE_ROOT which I used with $upload_filename $now = time();
while (file_exists($upload_filename = $upload_dir . $now .
                                     '-' .
                                     $_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'])) {
    $now++;
}

Answer (score -2):

What is that @ doing there? Remove it.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'], $upload_filename)
```

Comment: Apparently its to stop that function returning its own error. So im told. I removed it and still no dice